# What is the meaning of 'busts up a chiffarobe'?

Tags: meaning

According to this wikipedia entry http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chifforobe,

```
    "Chiffarobe" appears frequently in Harper Lee's novel To Kill a Mockingbird.[7] 
For instance, Tom Robinson "busts up a chiffarobe" for Mayella Ewell
```

What is the the meaning of this phrase?

Comment: You already have the definition of *chifforobe*. Better dictionaries will also tell you the definition of [bust up](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/busts_up#word=bust%20up). If those dictionary entries don't answer your question sufficiently, you need to explain why.

Comment: As someone who is not familiar with the time and the cultural context set in the book 'To Kill a Mockingbird', I do not know why there is a need to 'busts up a chiffarobe'. I will update my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A chiffarobe, as you see on the Wikipedia page, is a large piece of wooden furniture. In the story, Mayella asks Tom to bust to up, i.e. chop it to pieces, so that she will get firewood.